# Javascript Graph plugin to show values , Date Wise , Week wise and Month wise

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I have following values in JavaScript

**Variables**

```
var start= '29-10-2015';
var end= '29-12-2015';
var Targetvalue = parseFloat("1000000");
var dealjson = '[{"dealdate":"25-11-2015","cost":200000}]';
```

I want to show the performance in a graph according to week wise , day wise and month wise ,

For example between start and end there are 9 week so In the graph it should show in which week the deal was done and should compare to the target for the week which will be

`weeklyTarget = Targetvalue \totalnumberofweek`

`dailyTarget = Targetvalue \totalnumberofdays`

`monthlyTargte = Targetvalue \totalnumberofmonths`

Can any one suggest any plugin which I can use it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my Knowledge and experience you should use the [**chartjs**](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) library. Because its fulfill your requirements easily a its documentation was really very easy and understandable properly. Its also very Simple to use and provide multiple types of graphs and visualization also.

Comment: thanks for the link , But how will I match the dates its falling, I mean I want to show the week, days, months in the X axis

Comment: its very simple you can Simply append the data follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33094557/bar-graph-from-json-response/33094921?noredirect=1#comment54008420_33094921